# Extract both endpoints of hyperstreamline object (python VTK)

Tags: vtk

I am using VTK in Python to generate hyperstreamlines that are iterated in both directions from a starting point. I would like to extract the two (x,y,z) coordinate points corresponding to the ends of the hyperstreamline.

The point data for the hyperstreamline is stored in order of iteration, so its essentially two combined lists for each direction.

[Stream1_1,Stream1_2, ... ,Stream1_end,Stream2_1,Stream2_2, ... ,Stream2_end]

The last point is then the endpoint of the second stream. The endpoint of the first stream is somewhere in the middle of the list.

I can't find any information in the hyperstreamline object on how long each stream is to identify the index. I have tried methods such as Hyperstreamline.GetOutput().GetLength(), GetNumberofPieces(), etc. with no insight gained.

How can I determine both endpoints of the hyperstreamline object?

Comment: As far as I understand the hyperstreamline is represented by a surface. The method GetOutput() returns the surface as a PolyData object, which doesn't have clearly defined ends. On the other hand you can retrieve the start point by Hyperstreamline.GetStartPosition().

Comment: That's a good point, the hyperstreamline represents three scalars and is a surface; technically the idea of endpoint is a little poorly defined. I have 'solved' my issue by generating two single-direction-integrated hyperstreamlines instead of one doubly-integrated one, and extracting the last 'point' (in reality an arbitrary point on the final ovular cross section generated) of each. As the streamlines are thin and long this is sufficient for my purposes. Thank you for your insight.